# How could I start music streaming (possibly Spotify?) with the flick of a switch using Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, streaming

I think it would be awesome to be able to play music through a speaker by simply flicking a switch on or off, maybe remotely.  For example, the speaker would be at one end of the room and the switch we be next to the light switch on the opposite wall.  I am confident this is possible using a Raspberry Pi but am not entirely sure on how to do it.  Also, I know this would be achievable by simply leaving the music always running but I would like to have the streaming begin when the switch is activated.  Has anyone done this before, and could give me some tips, or point me to a tutorial?  Also, I have a Raspberry Pi 3 so that is what I would be using.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can write script that runs at startup and checks one of the RPi pins.
To the pin, you can solder the wire from the radio relay.
If the pin goes low or high (according to how you prefer it), the script runs the music, else stops the music.
The relay should be something like that: http://www.ebay.com/itm/12V-2-Channel-Wireless-Remote-Control-Radio-Relay-Switch-Transceiver-Receiver-/122550250269?hash=item1c88906b1d:g:fSsAAOSwRXRZQt0K
Of course you can do it with some http server and with a lot of another ways.
Good luck!
If you do it, please let us know :)